# Load a particular page in PPTX using react-doc-viewer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react-doc-viewer to load a pptx file in a react application.

Is there a way to go to a particular page in the ppt on button click ?

Any help is much appreciated

Note:
There was an issue with my sandbox link so removed it.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/file-viewer-hjsltq?

I am using the first method in the above link.

Thanks

Comment: I get the "Sandbox not found" error. Can you provide more context to reproduce your scenario?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule, thanks for replying. I have updated my question with an example i got from the internet.

Comment: So far from investigations, the office web viewer( which the react-doc-viewer is based upon) doesn't publish a programmatic interface to navigate through the slide pages.